# Keep my buttons from changing color on hover

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I have very nice buttons I'm happy with, but once a user clicks one, it changes the color of the text and how the button behaves when hovered on.  I used this generator to build the buttons:  http://twitterbootstrapbuttons.w3masters.nl/?color=%236f7578

Here's my button css:

```
.btn-custom-primary {
  background-color: hsl(0, 0%, 47%) !important;
  background-repeat: repeat-x !important;
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr="#777777", endColorstr="#777777");
  background-image: -khtml-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#777777), to(#777777));
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #777777, #777777);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #777777, #777777);
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #777777), color-stop(100%, #777777)) !important;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #777777, #777777) !important;
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #777777, #777777) !important;
  background-image: linear-gradient(#777777, #777777) !important;
  border-color: #777777 #777777 hsl(0, 0%, 47%);
  color: #fff !important;
  text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.00);
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}
```

Here's the example where the button works.  It's on a `submit_tag` attached to a form:

```
 <%= submit_tag 'Login', :class => "btn btn-custom-primary login-button" %>
```

Here's one of the bad buttons:

```
<%= link_to "Sign up", new_user_path, :class => "btn btn-custom-primary signup-button" %>
```

The additional class for each button is just for spacing:

```
.login-button, .create-account-button, .signup-button {
  margin-left: 5px;
  float: left;
}
```

I've also learned that this is not only for links that have been clicked before, but seemingly all buttons that are not `submit_tag`s.

Additionally, my navbar-collapse button is doing the same thing but changing to the color of the navbar:

```
<a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
```

This is what the button looks like when I hover after I've clicked it once:

[image]

This is what I want the button to look like while I hover on it:

[image]

Comment: Please post the relevant part of your HTML markup! Have you set several classes to the button element? Does this behaviour happen in all browsers, or with which one did you test it?

Comment: @Netsurfer is right, need to see more code with more info about the problem.  As seen in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tiri/3eDs4/ Your overriding css works fine with bootstrap 2.3 in chrome for me - not enough info to debug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hover background you're seeing is the `background-image` backdrop effect bootstrap adds to the buttons to make their buttons look 3d..ish. <del>You cab overcome this by simply removing the `background-image` effect in your `.btn-custom-primary` class, like so:</del>

It is done through the displacement of the `background-image` by shifting the gradient using the `background-position`, which can be removed like so:

```
.btn-custom-primary {
    background-position: 0 center;
}
```

Comment: Getting closer but that just makes the button completely clear on hover.\

Comment: @JoeEssey try this: http://jsbin.com/aHoToho/1 .. i missed the `background-position` changes as well.

Comment: Ilich, That displays appropriately for me.  I'm not sure what changes I need to make to my code though.

Comment: @JoeEssey sorry, let me update my answer, it was something totally different than what I wrote.